# Json Post through Android

Tags: android, json, database

I know how to parse data through JSON using android, but I have no idea how to send some data through it to the server and then on the basis on this data retrieve data through JSON to android application.  This is the code to parse the data to android:

```
private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {


        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
        // print the json response in the log
        Log.d("Get match fixture resps","> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("try", "in the try");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                int len = matchFixture.length();
                Log.d("len", "get array length");
                for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                    String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
                    Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                    String teamA = c.getString(TAG_TEAMA);
                    Log.d("teamA", teamA);
                    String teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                    Log.d("teamB", teamB);
                    //  hashmap for single match
                    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, teamA);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMB, teamB);
                    matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Doctor_Names.this, matchFixtureList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                TAG_MATCHID, TAG_TEAMA,TAG_TEAMB
        }
                , new int[] {
                R.id.teamA,R.id.name,
                R.id.teamB
        }
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }





}
```

But how do I POST data to PHP and then make some decisions?  Basically, I have the login page - its logged in correctly - but now I want to show data relative data according to the logged in person.  For that, I have to send the username of the desired person to the server.  I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Try using volley...check out [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: this website is is usefull do you know some thing better its my final year project and i search alot but find nothing

Comment: You need to use HttpUrlConnection to make an http request to the webserver.  Use the POST method, and attach the Json object, converted to a string, as the body of the post.

There's various libraries that will handle a lot of the grunt work for you, but that's basically what they'll be doing in the background.

Comment: can you recommend me any website i am just stuck here

Answer (score -2):

OkHttp ([tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html))
and Volley ([tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/))
 are the best libraries out there to handle request and response.

You can use anyone of them. It's both simple and straightforward.